# Error in R data.table fwrite()?

Tags: r, data.table

I discovered unexpected behavior in data.table::fwrite: future dates reset to 1901. I was using the year 2999 to mask an unspecified date for determining whether an event occurred before a certain date.

Here's my example:

```
> library("data.table", lib.loc="~/Library/R/3.5/library")
data.table 1.11.4  Latest news: http://r-datatable.com
> DT <- data.table(A=1:5)
> DT[1, D:=as.POSIXct("2018-01-01")]
> DT[2, D:=as.POSIXct("2020-12-31")]
> DT[3, D:=as.POSIXct("2040-12-31")]
> DT[4, D:=as.POSIXct("2099-12-31")]

> dput(DT)
structure(list(A = 1:5, D = structure(c(1514793600, 1609401600, 
2240553600, 4102387200, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone =  "")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103833ce0>)
```

It prints on the console as expected:

```
> DT

   A          D
1: 1 2018-01-01
2: 2 2020-12-31
3: 3 2040-12-31
4: 4 2099-12-31
5: 5       <NA>
```

However, when using fwrite() either to a file or console, some of the dates change:

```
> fwrite(DT, file = "")
A,D
1,2018-01-01T08:00:00Z
2,2020-12-31T08:00:00Z
3,1901-12-14T.�48364Z
4,1901-12-14T.�48364Z
5,
```

Somewhere between 2030 and 2040 the dates change to 1901. I (10 decimal digits) shouldn't be running up against the limit of double number representation (15 decimal digits). Any ideas?

macos 10.13.6;  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02);   data.table 1.11.4

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` uses a function written in C to do all the work, with custom handlers for dates and datetimes used by default.  I suggest creating an issue on the [package's GitHub page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).

Until then, this works:

```
fwrite(DT, dateTimeAs = "write.csv")
# A,D
# 1,2018-01-01
# 2,2020-12-31
# 3,2040-12-31
# 4,2099-12-31
# 5,
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. My work-around was using a date slightly less in the future, 2030 works fine.